# Puede haber una imagen dentro de un header? seo

Tags: seo

Estoy reestructurando unos bloques de página y quería saber si puedo poner una etiqueta de tipo `img` dentro de un `header` ¿Es correcto? o simplemente un *figure>img* la estructura es la siguiente :

```
<section>
    <header>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" alt="">
    </header>
    <h2></h2>
    <article>
        <a href=""><span></span> </a>
        <a href=""><span></span> </a>
        <a href=""><span></span> </a>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Técnicamente si. Todo lo demás son opiniones.

Comment: La especificación dice: _"A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading (an h1–h6 element), but this is not required. The header element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents, a search form, or any relevant logos."_  Así que aunque lo normal es que un `header` lleve elementos `h1-h6` no es obligatorio y puede contener también otros elementos.

Comment: Tampoco necesitas el `figure>image`, eso dependerá del tipo y contenido de la imagen.

Answer (score 2):

**Definición y Uso Header**

El `<header>` representa un contenedor para el contenido de introducción o un conjunto de enlaces de navegación.

Un elemento `<header>` normalmente contiene:

- uno o más elementos de encabezado ( - )
- logotipo o icono
- información de autoría

Así que por definición sí que puedes poner una etiqueta `img`.

Lo que **NO** se puede hacer con el `<header>`:

- No se puede colocar dentro de un elemento `<pie de página>`.
- No se puede colocar dentro de un elemento `<dirección>`.
- No se puede colocar dentro de otro elemento `<header>`.

Puedes encontrar más información aquí, es una buena web de referencia:

http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_header.asp